# Difference between p and puts

Tags: arrays, ruby

Why in below code when I

p the object it returns array of integers #=> [[1, 2, 4]]

puts the object it returns array of single integers #=>1
                                                       2
                                                       4

Class of single integers is still an array, but I do not understand why they return as single numbers. Thanks

````
class Matrix
  attr_reader :rows, :columns

  def initialize(source)
    @rows = parse_rows_from_source(source)
    @columns = @rows.transpose
  end

  private

  def parse_rows_from_source(source)
    source.lines.map { |line| line.split.map(&:to_i)}
  end
end

p Matrix.new("1, 2/n3, 4").rows```
````

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of `Kernel#p` and `Kernel#puts`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future programmers don't face the same problems you do. In other words: please, help make the world a better place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p object` is equal to `puts object.inspect`

That's the main difference.

[`Object#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) returns a string containing a human-readable representation of object.